# No slashes stored in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

this is a simplified version of my code. What I'm trying to achive is that I want to insert the image path into a DB table. I used the constant DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR and I am also using PDO.

```
$tmp    = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
$name   = $_FILES['file1']['name'];
$path   = getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'images' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $name;



$success = move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path);


if($success){
    $query = "INSERT INTO phptbl (Name, Photo) VALUES ('name', '$path')";
    $db->exec($query);
}else{
    echo 'Something went wrong!';
}
```

Data will be inserted into the table without directory separation.

Please advise

Comment: Is the `DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR` a backslash on your system...?

Comment: Yea, I am using Windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR` is `\` on your system, you're creating a string with backslashes. Backslashes are an escape character in many languages, including SQL. The database will interpret `\` as a meta character. To correctly store any and all arbitrary values, you need to either escape the value correctly (to `\\`) or, better, **prepare and bind** the query:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO phptbl (Name, Photo) VALUES ('name', ?)";
$stmt->execute([$path]);
```

This will correctly preserve special characters as is without them getting interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

Use prepared query, it will protects you from problems with slashes, quotes and other special characters

Try next:

```
$tmp    = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
$name   = $_FILES['file1']['name'];
$path   = getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'images' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $name;



$success = move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path);


if($success){
    $query = "INSERT INTO phptbl (Name, Photo) VALUES ('name', :path)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare();
    $stmt->execute([':path' => $path]);
}else{
    echo 'Something went wrong!';
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try" this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.